# Find all Java versions in the system path

Tags: linux, bash, admin

I needed to know a command to find all of the versions of Java in the system path. I knew that `which -a java` would print all places that the java executable can be found in the system path, but I then wanted to get the version info for each of these executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which -a java | xargs -I{} echo "echo {};{} -version;echo" | sh`

This will print the path to each of the java executables found in the system path, as well as the version information of that executable, and separate entries with a newline. It works like so:

1. Pipe the output from `which -a java` into xargs
2. Use `xargs -I{} echo` to construct `bash` commands, with each line in the input from `which` replacing `{}`
3. Pipe the constructed `bash` commands into the system's default shell executor.

A sample output on my machine gives

```
/usr/bin/java
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Note that if you want to know the versions of a different executable, you can modify the bash command that gets constructed to appropriately print version info. E.G. if you want to know all the versions of `python` you can run

`which -a python | xargs -I{} echo "echo {};{} --version;echo" | sh`